# Flutter Doctor found issues in 2 categories

Tags: flutter, dart

I have updated my mac os to 10.15 Beta, unfortunately after that my flutter application started working abnormally, initially there was a dart extension permission exception resolved now and have gone through below mentioned link and achieved some more error, now after I ran flutter doctor -v in my pc I got the following please help me out to resolve this, thanks in advance.

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A471t, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /Users/harshavardhan/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (6 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information



[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/harshavardhan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    ✗ Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run.
      Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted.
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone Xʀ • 3999B2E6-E5DD-4726-9A0D-8B17A3CA5674 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Link is here::
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21859

Comment: This is solution for issue no - 2  -  Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run.
      Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted.

Comment: And for issue no - 1 please refer the provided url in log of flutter doc

Comment: Yeah I have gone through the link but the result I got is t install some `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6` I tried `brew install` it didn't work for the 1st one

Comment: and no -2 Xcode is not giving any option to install additional required components, in fact, I opened Xcode and tried.

Comment: I have ran through all the issues and found a temp solution. Temp solution is to remove armv7 and armv7s from valid architecture in build settings it drops support for iphone 5 and 5s and iPad 4 and other older device. Do give a try to this solution.

Comment: I guess this issue here is because in the latest update of iOS those devices are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

With the current details at hand, it looks like your flutter checkout has missing required files. A fix for this issue is by either doing a rollback or install Flutter fresh.